# Wave Analytics Filter by Formula field

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics, saql

Is it possible to filter the rows based on the formula fields. I created a table
and I only need to show rows that is not in <=-25% && >= 25%.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Just follow this syntax

> s = filter s by 'Rapport Scan' >= -25 && 'Rapport Scan' <= 25;